# Image Interpolation in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use interpolation to remove chromatic aberration from an image.  The code I have generates the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.  Below is my code - any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you- Areej
This is an input explanation

```
#splitting an image into its separe bands
source = im.split()
Cfixed = source[2]
Cwarp  = source[1]
#take the image minus a ew-wide edge
roi = [ew+1, xdim-ew, ew+1, ydim-ew];
roi_pad = [roi[0]-ew, roi[1]+ew, roi[2]-ew, roi[3]+ew];
for k in range(0,centers_x.size):
        cx = centers_x[k]
        cy = centers_y[k]
        wz = warps[k]     
import scipy as sp
from scipy import interpolate

def warpRegion(Cwarp, roi_pad, (cx, cy, wz)):
    #Unpack region indices
    sx, ex, sy, ey = roi_pad
    xramp, yramp = np.mgrid[sx:ex+1, sy:ey+1]
    shapeofgrid=xramp.shape
    print 'shape of x grid'+str(shapeofgrid)
    xrampc = xramp - cx;
    yrampc = yramp - cy;
    xramp1 = 1/wz*xrampc;
    yramp1 = 1/wz*yrampc;
    xrampf = xrampc.flatten()
    yrampf = yrampc.flatten() 
    xramp1f = xramp1.flatten()
    yramp1f = yramp1.flatten()
    reg_w = sp.interpolate.interp2d(yrampf,xrampf,Cwarp, yramp1f, xramp1f,'cubic');
```

Comment: Please add some code that generates example input data (as well as probably the numpy/scipy import statements)

Comment: source = im.split()
 Cfixed = source[2]
 Cwarp  = source[1]#take the image minus a ew-wide edge
  roi = [ew+1, xdim-ew, ew+1, ydim-ew];

Comment: I mean add it to the code so that it's a complete but minimal (i.e. without any unimportant extra code) example. You need to help people help you, so if they can take your code and run it directly then you're much more likely to get your problem fixed. Also, can you add the full error message - e.g. including the line number

Comment: I am so sorry about that I am trying to figure out how to format this properly

Comment: I reposted the question again at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414204/chromatic-aberration-estimation-in-python

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation of the error message is that you are trying to use a NumPy array as a dict key or a set element. Look at where the error occurs and study the type of every variable referenced on that line. If you need help, post a runnable example and the full traceback of the exception.

Comment: I reposted the question at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414204/chromatic-aberration-estimation-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using PIL. (Python Image Library)

http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

One method would be to:
Generate a list of top colours per quadrant/sample area and hash the list