# Chromatic Aberration Estimation in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hi this code estimates chromatic aberration in an image by giving the center of distortion (x,y) and magnitude of distortion (alpha) between the red and green channels and also between the blue and green channels.  I have an error in the WarpRegion function

```
File "CAfeb.py", line 217, in warpRegion
    reg_w = sp.interpolate.interp2d(yrampf,xrampf,Cwarp, yramp1f, xramp1f,'cubic');
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 109, in __init__
    'quintic' : 5}[kind]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Below is the complete code - Any help will be greatly appreciated-Thank you. Areej

```
import math
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal
import scipy as sp
from scipy import interpolate
from scitools.std import ndgrid
from scipy import ogrid, sin, mgrid, ndimage, array


def ldimage():
    #load image
    global im
    im = Image.open("/home/areej/Desktop/mandril_color.tif") 

def analyzeCA(mode, im):
    n_regions = 10;
    reg_size = [300, 300];
    overlap = 0.5;


    levels = 9;
    steps = 2;
    edge_width = 10;
    hist_sz = 128;

   # alpha_1 and alpha_2 are assumed to be between these values
    w_data = [0.9985, 1.0015];

    reg_list=[]

   #creating an array of pixels so that we can access them
    pix=im.load()

#
#Analyze full image

    if mode=='full':
        print "Doing a full analysis"
        # mx_shift is the third argument in 'full' mode
        mx_shift = n_regions;
            # [ydim,xdim,zdim]= size(im);
        ydim=im.size[0]
        xdim=im.size[1]
        zdim=3

        print "Image dimensions: [ydim, xdim, zdim]= "+str([ydim,xdim,zdim])


        global alpha_mx, alpha_mn
        alpha_mx = 1 + 4*mx_shift / math.sqrt( xdim*xdim + ydim*ydim );
        alpha_mn = 1.0/alpha_mx;

        print "alpha_mx= "+str(alpha_mx)
        print "alpha_mn= "+str(alpha_mn)
        #recompute alpha_1 and alpha_2 to be between
        #these new values
        w_data = [alpha_mn, alpha_mx];
        ew = edge_width;

        #take the image minus a ew-wide edge
        roi = [ew+1, xdim-ew, ew+1, ydim-ew];

        print "edge_width= "+str(ew)
        print "roi= "+str(roi)

        #Analyze blue to green chromatic aberration
        bg_params = parameterSearch( im, [3, 2], roi, ew, hist_sz, w_data);

        # Analyze red to green chromatic aberration
        rg_params = parameterSearch( im, [1, 2], roi, ew, hist_sz, w_data );
    elif mode=='reg':
      print "we should do a regional analysis here"

    else:
     print "unsupported call"
#def estimateCARegions( im, [3, 2], reg_list, settings ):
def parameterSearch( im, colour_space, roi, ew, hist_sz, w_data):

    #levels is number of iterations 
    levels = 8;
    steps = 2;

    #[ydim,xdim,zdim] = size(im);
    ydim=im.size[0]
    xdim=im.size[1]
    zdim= 3


    x_data = [1, xdim];
    y_data = [1, ydim];

    xlim = x_data;
    ylim = y_data;
    zlim = w_data;

#work out which of height and width is the bigger
    dim = max(xdim,ydim)

    print "The highest dimension is : "+str(dim)

#check that roi falls within expected boundries
    if ((roi[0] <= ew) or (roi[1] > xdim-ew) or (roi[2] <= ew) or (roi[3] > ydim-ew)):
        print "ROI is too close to image edges"
        return -1 # TODO: terminate here with an error
        #Get image regions

    source = im.split()
    Cfixed = source[2]
    Cwarp  = source[1]
    #[ydim,xdim,zdim] = size(im);
    ydimCwarp=Cwarp.size[0]
    xdimCwarp=Cwarp.size[1]
    print 'xdimCwarp'+str(xdimCwarp)

    roi_pad = [roi[0]-ew, roi[1]+ew, roi[2]-ew, roi[3]+ew];
    for levels in range(1,8):
    #Guess at a center and then compute best warp
    #user defined function linear_space used to generate linearly spaced vectors
        x_coords = np.linspace(0,511,steps+2)
        y_coords = np.linspace(0,511,steps+2)
        z_coords = np.linspace(alpha_mn,alpha_mx,steps+2)
        step_x=(xlim[1]-xlim[0])/(steps+1)
        start_x=xlim[0]+step_x
        end_x=xlim[1]-step_x+0.5
        step_y=(ylim[1]-ylim[0])/(steps+1)
        start_y=ylim[0]+step_y
        end_y=ylim[1]-step_y+0.5
        step_z=(zlim[1]-zlim[0])/(steps+1)
        start_z=zlim[0]+step_z
        fudge_z=step_z/2.0
        end_z=zlim[1]-step_z+fudge_z
        #Do not include end points in search;
        centers_x, centers_y, warps= np.mgrid[start_x:end_x:step_x,start_y:end_y:step_y,start_z:end_z:step_z]
        centers_x=centers_x.flatten()
        centers_y=centers_y.flatten()
        warps=warps.flatten()
        mi = np.zeros(centers_x.size)

        for k in range(0,centers_x.size):
           cx = centers_x[k]
           cy = centers_y[k]
           wz = warps[k]       
           #Warp the region 
           temp_im = warpRegion(Cwarp, roi_pad, [cx, cy, wz])
                #correlation
           mi[k] = np.corrcoef(Cfixed, temp_im)
               #Now pick the best quadrant
        v, max_ix = math.max(mi)
        ix, jx, kx = arrayInd(mi.size, max_ix);
        ##The coordinates of err are off by 1 from x_coords and y_coords because
        ##we did not include the end point
    xlim = x_coords([jx, jx+2]);
    ylim = y_coords([ix, ix+2]);
    zlim = z_coords([kx, kx+2]);

    cx = math.mean(xlim);
    cy = math.mean(ylim);
    wz = math.mean(zlim);

    print "x= "+str(cx)
    print "y= "+str(cy)
    print "z= "+str(wz)
def warpRegion(Cwarp, roi_pad, (cx, cy, wz)):
#Unpack region indices
    sx, ex, sy, ey = roi_pad

    xramp, yramp = np.mgrid[sx:ex+1, sy:ey+1]

    xrampc = xramp - cx;
    yrampc = yramp - cy;
    xramp1 = 1/wz*xrampc;
    yramp1 = 1/wz*yrampc;
    xrampf = xrampc.flatten()
    yrampf = yrampc.flatten()
    xramp1f = xramp1.flatten()
    yramp1f = yramp1.flatten()
    reg_w = sp.interpolate.interp2d(yrampf,xrampf,Cwarp, yramp1f, xramp1f,'cubic');

ldimage()
analyzeCA('full', im)
```

Comment: What error do you have? And please format your code properly, your "runnable" code most certainly is not runnable.

Comment: This is the error I get (File "CAfeb.py", line 217, in warpRegion reg_w = sp.interpolate.interp2d(yrampf,xrampf,Cwarp, yramp1f, xramp1f,'cubic'); File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 109, in init 'quintic' : 5}[kind] TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray')

Comment: @AreejF: that doesn't look like the call syntax for interp2d, which only accepts three array arguments and a few flags, and returns a function.  Type `help(interpolate.interp2d)` for the details.

Comment: Be careful. You have 5 questions with no accepted answers. You'll likely not get the attention you want if you're not reciprocating.

Answer (score 1):

As DSM states correctly this is not the correct calling syntax for interp2d which can be viewed at [scipy.interp2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html). If you would read the calling syntax and then your error message again (or the module itself whichever you prefer) you would recognize that you are trying to use an array as index for a dictionary which will naturally throw an exception.

I think what you are trying to do is an interpolation of the grid given by the arrays xrampf, yrampf at the new positions xrampf1, yrampf1. The scipy documentation also gives an exact same usage example which translate as following to your code:

```
interp_func = sp.interpolate.interp2d(yrampf, xrampf, Cwarp, kind='cubic')
reg_w = interp_func(yramp1f, xramp1f)
```

I hope that was your intention to do.

Kind regards